# Auto Find on Entry is not working on a header detail form

Tags: erp, jdedwards

I have a Find browse form from which am passing a value to the form control of Header detail form with Auto find on Entry enabled in Grid. I have called the Header detail form in the select button of the find browse form. But the header detail form's grid appear blank and doesnt show up any value.

Note :I am working on JD Edwards "Standalone" 
App release : E910
Tool release: 9.1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

For the "Auto Find" option to work, the data items from your data structure must be put on the form as filtering items. When there is at least one data item with a value, the auto find kicks in.
[image: Data Structure]
[image: Adding a filtering data item]

You could also do the find manually in the "Post Dialog is Initialized" by calling the system functions "General > Press Button (FIND)". This would then look like this
[image: Event rules]

Answer (score 0):

Further to GELR's response, oracle has made of point in 9.1 of enforcing users to add some filter criteria before enquiring on a form. There is no point in opening an application and auto-finding on nothing, that's a massive (unnecessary) hit on the DB.